# visual studio c# determine components with Random

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, events, random, event-handling

The title is a bit confusing, as I didn't know how to word it. My question is this:

I am building a visual studio form with a bunch of buttons (all in rows and columns to make a big square). I'm using Random.Next() to generate a random number.

I want the button number that corresponds with the random number to do something;  e.g. If the random number is 7 and button 7 is then clicked, it will execute the code.  But if the random number is 7 and button 8 is clicked, the code will not execute.

Is there a way to do this without a ton of if/else or switch statements? Because I have around 80 buttons.

Comment: I'd use a `Dictionary<int,Action>` or similar.  This question is far too vague to get a decent answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a good opportunity to (ab)use the `Tag` property.

You would simply set the `Tag` of each button control to its associated number, and then check it against the randomly generated value.

```
if (randValue.ToString() == (sender as Button).Tag)
{
   ...
}
```

Definitely not the cleanest design, but it would work.